# paramiko - "Not a valid OpenSSH/RSA/... private key" error

Tags: paramiko, ssh-keys

When I am using `paramiko 2.4.0`, I continue to receive errors like this:

```
SSHException: not a valid OPENSSH private key file
```

While I can use the key to `ssh` to the machine, and the remote is reachable.

The key is generated by:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then I copy the public key to the remote machine:(the path can be private key, too, it is the same)

```
ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/public/key root@remote_host
```

Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that the mechanism of detecting key errors in `paramiko` is... *too simple, sometimes naive*. As indicated by [#340](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/340) and [#387](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/387), there are some known issues.

At last it turned out that it is not the problem of the key; the message is confusing. It is problem of username/permission/duplication.

**`paramiko` will try to login with the user you use in the key, because it assumes that user also exists on the remote machine.** But I think this logic is wrong, because basically when you use cryptography login, you don't need a username; you have the private key and the server has the public key, and that's all what it requires.

Imagine this scenario: you generate a key with Windows, and you are `john` here, your public key will have `john@myhost` in the `authorized_keys` file. When you `connect()` without `username`, you actually are login with `john` in another Linux machine, which may not have this user. If you are on a Linux, it is better, because if you generate the key with `root`, in another machine it has `root`, too, and `root` may have the correct permission on the public key file.

So, at last, I was able to solve the problem by:

- in the remote machine, examine `authorized_keys` file to eliminate any duplicated lines of same `user@host`.
- after generating the public key, change it so that `user` in it is a valid user on **remote** machine. Yes it seems strange, but it is how `paramiko` works. Then copy it to remote.
- when calling `connect()`, pass in the `username` arg to be the same username you put in the public key.
- make sure the user you used in public key has right permission on the `authorized_keys` file, and its parent `.ssh` folder. At least `r` permission.

Comment: I changed the user name to much with the user name on the remote machine as @WesternGun suggested, but I am still getting: "paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file". My key file start with:-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAA

Comment: Well, this is _indeed_ not a RSA private key.. This is in another format. OpenSSH key can convert this into a PEM format, like in this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/939909/ssh-keygen-does-not-create-rsa-private-key
What I got in the post, was a RSA key recognized as OpenSSH key, but your case is the opposite.